Munki Silent Software Installation
I am relatively new to Munki and MDM.
I have now installed Munki on a Mac and so far the other Mac clients are also supplied with software.
However, I would now like to set up 1-2 software systems so that they are installed silently without the user having to update them.
In Munki I have already selected the Unattended Install method in the pkg file, but how can I now set it so that the desired installation process runs as described above?
